# Why the change between English and French in Anatomy of a Fall?

Tags: dialogue, anatomy-of-a-fall

In *Anatomy of a Fall*, the characters live in France, but since the main character, Sandra, is not herself French (nor does she speak it too well), most of her dialogue is spoken in English.

This includes her appearances in court where after not too long of attempting to give her evidence in French, she gives up and speaks in English for the rest of the case, resulting in a rather strange Star-Wars-ish scenario of her being questioned in French, understanding perfectly, and responding in English.

Why was it done this way, as opposed to having all the characters just speak French? (as in, from a creative, out-of-universe point of view, not just "because she's German")

Comment: There are plenty of languages I understand better than I speak them. In the two years before CoViD-19, I traveled a lot, and much to my own surprise, I observed myself following technical discussions in French (French, Canadian, and Belgian), Italian, Spanish (Castilian and Argentinian), Portuguese (Portuguese and Brazilian), Catalan, Dutch (Dutch and Belgian), and Norwegian, and even a tiny bit of Japanese and Korean, enough to be able to grasp the broad strokes. But in each case, I was only ever able to respond in English. So, this sounds pretty normal to me.

Comment: Note that whether any court would allow this in real life is a different question. Courts are generally rather keen on making sure everybody understands exactly what's going on, so they would probably insist on interpreters.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - The French court in the film does have an interpreter. The audience seed involved parties putting on earpieces. (I also understand several languages better than I speak them, so for me, that aspect had a lot of impact. Her vulnerability was clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justine Triet, who directed and co-wrote the screenplay, [explained](https://slate.com/culture/2023/10/anatomy-of-a-fall-ending-explained-justine-triet-interview.html) that she herself had a complicated relationship with language, which she wanted to make a prominent feature of the movie.

> Interviewer: Sandra has to switch between French and English, and French is difficult and English is easier for her. It’s also an issue with Samuel, what language she uses. What role does language-switching play in your life, and why did you want to explore it in the movie?

> ...Triet (through a translator): So first, my relationship to language has changed and moved a lot. When I was younger, it was not something that I was comfortable with. I had kind of a relationship of timidity to it. Understanding the ways in which language could be a place where certain weapons could be gotten to help oneself, how to get out of delicate situations, and sort of to appropriate that arsenal of language, was something that was a process for me. And then to get back to the film itself, it is a very central preoccupation. We kind of move between different zones of language, one being the impulsive language of home and of intimacy, in which somehow language is always defeated to the attempt to communicate. And then, in the courtroom, language in an analytical register that is going to try and help us control reality. That is much more a cerebral and colder relationship with language. So I was interested in developing both these registers, and seeing how we move from one to the other.

Sandra's inability to speak English during the trial evokes a sense of loss of control over her words and their actual meaning.

Uncertainty is another dominant theme in the movie, as evidenced by Sandra's son demanding of his court appointed overseer her opinion on whether or not his mother is guilty. She refuses to say, and tells him instead that he has to choose what to believe, not to pretend, but to make a choice and live with it. And that's what we're given by the movie, the knowledge that unknowns exist and we must make choices based on the unknown.

<sub>My first language was French, but as I live in the US, my native language changed to English. I understand French quite well, but can't speak it fluently, and I understand the filmmaker's point about language, as I quite often see mismatches between what is spoken and what the caption states. Some of the differences are idiomatic, and some maybe because the caption would be too long to read quickly, but there are definitely mismatches.</sub>